# OpenCV function to calculate angle of a pixel formed with the centre of the image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I need to find the angle of a pixel formed with the center of an image. Is there a function to perform this as cv2.cartToPolar in OpenCV? I need to find alpha for all the pixels.[image: I need to find alpha for all the pixels]

Comment: What do you mean by saying for all the pixels? Does your hand-writing numbers and letters will be exist in th sample image ?

Comment: See cv2.warpPolar() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga49481ab24fdaa0ffa4d3e63d14c0d5e4